# Why does a counter variable need to be reset when looping through a sorted Array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

The following code follows the .sort() life cycle of an array of numbers. Everything seems to make sense except for one detail toward the bottom - where the "p" variable is reset to 0 after each iteration of the for loop. If someone could explain why the p needs to be reset each time I would be in your debt!

```
    let arr = [90, 1, 20, 14, 3, 55];
    var sortRes = [];
    var copy = arr.slice();
    var inc = 0;
    copy.sort((a, b) => {
        sortRes[inc] = [a, b, a - b]; // Array(3) 12 times 
        inc += 1; // inc -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.9.10,11,12 
        return a - b;
    });

    let p = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inc; i++) { // i -> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11  ... 0 < 12,  1 < 12,  2 < 12..etc.

        copy = arr.slice(); // copy each sorted copy of arr and override it with... 
        copy.sort((a, b) => { // ...another sort

            p++;

            if (p <= i) {
                console.log(p);
                return a - b;
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        });

        p = 0; 
        console.log(copy + " \t a: " + sortRes[i][0] + " \tb: " + sortRes[i][1] + "\tTotal: " + sortRes[i][2]);

    }
```

Comment: It actually should be reset *before* each loop iteration and `sort()` call, but resetting it afterwards achieves the same result.

Comment: `return false;` is horribly wrong. It looks like this code attempts to reproduce the array state after each comparison step, but it won't work like that. No point in trying to understand what it does.